# Discord keeps crashing randomly

Tags: terminal, crash, troubleshooting, application, discord

Discord on my computer crashes constantly at random intervals. Sometimes I can use it for hours without issues, other times it crashes just 10 minutes after starting. I **thought** that this had to do with the streaming software, **so through the settings I turned off all hardware acceleration on the app, but it still didn't fix it**.

I opened it through the terminal and used it for a while, when it finally crashed this is what I got back:

(the crash showed an empty line)

`Failed to get crash dump id.`

`Report Id: 2d1c5958-f780-43`

`Segmentation fault`

When opening the app, the terminal also returned that my Discord was up to date and there were no new updates available. There was also an optional module line which read: `Optional module ./ElectronTestRpc was not included.`

Some information that may be useful:

1. The flatpak version of Discord does **not** crash, but after some hours of use, **whether streaming my screen or not**, the app lags and becomes unresponsive. This does not happen in the regular version.
2. On a post from around 2 years ago I saw people complaining that this crash had something do to with the **glibc** package not being updated or not working, I'm not sure if it still applies.
3. **I have been dealing with this issue since Discord updated to version 0.0.20**, that is exactly when it started and no amount of reinstalling, fixing broken packages and updating and cleaning the system has fixed it.
4. In my personal experience the crashes happen **mostly** when I am streaming my screen, either gaming or not, but not **exclusively**. Sometimes it just happens when I'm in a call.

So, how do I fix Discord so that it will stop crashing?

Comment: Do you have `polychromatic` installed? You could try to downgrading the package to the previous version... which distro are you using?

Comment: @telometto I'm on Debian 11. I've thought about downgrading, but I would like to keep up with the discord updates to see if they eventually add audio to streaming.

Comment: still no fix for this

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten about this. I'm pretty sure this has to do with Debian/Discord itself. You should report this as a bug, since I suspect that the Electron package is out of date, or outright EOL.

Comment: @telometto The electron package was not loaded, the message says it is optional, so you're probably right about it being out of date, but I don't think that it's the cause of the problem.

Comment: I still need a solution for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have `libappindicator1` installed. If you have, uninstall it using `apt remove`. Then try:

- `# apt install libayatana-appindicator1`
- Change the dependency in the control file - this can be done by hand or by using a script.

Script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
PKG=$1
TMP_PATH=pkg/$1
CTRL=$TMP_PATH/DEBIAN/control
mkdir -p $TMP_PATH
dpkg-deb -x $1 $TMP_PATH
dpkg-deb --control $1 $TMP_PATH/DEBIAN
sed -i s,libappindicator1,libayatana-appindicator1,g $CTRL 
dpkg -b $TMP_PATH fixed-$1
```

- `chmod +x <script name>.sh`
- Download Discord from their website.
- Run `<script name>.sh <name of downloaded discord>.deb`
- Install the resulting package that gets spit out by the script: `dpkg -i <package name>.deb`.

If this doesn't work, I think you're out of luck; given the fact that downgrading doesn't seem to be an option. If snaps don't bother you, you'll have to see if the snap package works, since the flatpak package doesn't seem to work for you either.

**EDIT:** forgot to mention that I found an answer in [this](https://old.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/qayyi2/discord_keeps_crashing_at_random_times/hhcrnqy/) Reddit post.